# CSS issue on IE7 - Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css, xhtml, navigation

I have designed a Navigation Menu, it working properly on Chrome, Firefox and IE8.

It appear it not working properly on IE7, the margin and the size of the `<li>` is too small, sub-menu is not appearing in full and also `#background` is missing.

It should look the same as Chrome and Firefox.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/FFWfp/

How to fix this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="background"> 
   <div class="nav-block">
                <ul id="nav">
                <li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li>

                <li>
                <a href="/">Category</a>
                  <ul class='subnav'> 
                   <li><a href='#'>PHP </a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>HTML</a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>CSS</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="/">Account</a>
                  <ul class='subnav'> 
                   <li><a href='#'>One</a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>Two</a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/admin/reports">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>

#background  {
 background-color:#EBE9E1;
 overflow:hidden;
}

 .nav-block{
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
}

#nav {
    padding:12px;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav li{
    display:inline;
    margin:0 1px 0 -1px;
    padding:3px 15px;
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;
}

#nav a {
    background-color:white;
    color:#C51721;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav .subnav {
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
    width:130px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    color:#000000;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    background-color:white;
}

#nav .subnav li {
    padding:0px;
    float: none;
    width:100px;
    color:#000000;
    margin:0px;
}

#nav .subnav li a {
    padding:3px;
    padding-left:10px;
    display:block;
    background-color:white;
    color:#C51721;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;
}
 </style>
```

Comment: Perhaps this cross-browser menu example could help you http://bit.ly/flFwTo

Comment: @red, I don't want dropdown functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be simple, clearfix, containing floats whatever.. but it's not This is a hasLayout error that compounds, it is one of the rare situations where you need to remove haslayout, but where it's not possible to do so.

The way your code is written (nothing wrong with it by the way!) means the `#background div` **needs** hasLayout to contain the floated children (even trying an extra clearing element doesn't work which shows the out and out IE error). Your code has this with `overflow : hidden;`, but then because there's hasLayout on the `.nav-block` due to the 50px height, that height, in IE7, is all that's being "contained" - this is of course wrong, as the floated lists are children of `#background` too.. however it's because of an error that hasLayout even works to contain floats so there's no use arguing the specs!

I tried every hack I knew how and but the simplest way was to rewrite the code and avoid hasLayout where possible, and use margins and line-heights instead - so I reversed the coloring of the two containing blocks. I made the `background` black and the `.nav-block` grey & gave the background a top padding of 50px to make the black bar.. then I moved the menu which is inside the grey bit up by 43px with a negative top margin. it's 43px because in your example I measure the black bar @ 50px; and the top links @ 36px in height which meant to keep them looking vertically centered on the black bar they would have need `50px-36px = 14px / 2 = 7px` top & bottom 'spacing'.

the `.nav-block` div then needed to be the one that was made to contain the floated children, but `overflow: hidden` won't work now because of the negative top margin, it would hide the top links! so instead I floated it left and gave it a width of 100%; which is another way of creating a new block formatting context and giving IE the hasLayout it needs without clipping the content.

then I pretty much followed what you had done to achieve the short top links and full width (130px) child links only floating the top links so they would "shinkwrap" - without the float on the child lists the child links could be made `display: block` so they take the full width of the `ul`. For the height on the top links IE needed both line-height and padding, but `line-height` on the child links was enough because of the `display: block;`

#### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/bvfY6/)

HTML is the same as yours above..

CSS:

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#background  { /* black bar */
    background: #000;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.nav-block {
    background: #EBE9E1;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#nav, #nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav { /* black bar = 50px, top links = 36px, difference = 14px, = 7px from top */
    margin-top: -43px;
}

#nav ul {
    width:130px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    margin-left:-2px;
}

#nav > li { /* top links only */
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}

#nav a {
    line-height: 36px;
    background-color:white;
    color:#C51721;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul a { /* child list links */
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful! I have learnt a lot from your code.. I hope it would help me in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you either have to comment out the spaces between or put all your `<li>` elements on one line.

E.g.:

```
<ul class='subnav'> 
<li><a href='#'>PHP </a></li><!--
--><li><a href='#'>HTML</a></li><!--
--><li><a href='#'>CSS</a></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul class='subnav'> 
<li><a href='#'>PHP </a></li><li><a href='#'>HTML</a></li><li><a href='#'>CSS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in learning css.
I reccomend using this example as your guideline: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

The background for #background isn't appearing because it contains only floated elements.
You can fix this bey giving it a set height in css, or by using the "clearfix" method ( http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/ )